# Pycharm run terminal garbage output when running Odoo

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, odoo, ubuntu-18.04, odoo-11

You can see the garbage output at the last line:
[image: t]
When this happens new output is not printed anymore.

system info:
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Which version of Odoo ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-d database_name -u module_name` to upgrade the module, then only will print the result.

Comment: Can you explain how this will fix the issue? also I don't want to upgrade my module every time I run Odoo.

Comment: Which version of Odoo you are using ?

Comment: It is in the tags, Odoo 11